# How to clear a specific line in the console window

Tags: c++, windows

I'm making a text based top down game in c++,every time I move my player  I need to clear the whole console window with system("CLS") and after that print the whole world again. That process is really slow and inefficient. My question is whether there is any function to clear a certain line in the console window that will not affect the rest of the text? For example, look at the code.

Thanks :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;




int main()
{

cout << "hello\n";
cout << "world\n";

//Output: 
//        hello
//        world

//Wanted Output:    

//
//         world
system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

I expect text to be printed on the screen and then one line will be cleared without affecting the rest of the text

Comment: You need to use the Windows Console API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions

Comment: I know it's not relevant in this case, but under linux I used `system("echo -en \"\\033[1A\" ");` and it worked for me. It is actually a command for bash shells

Answer (score 0):

The win32-API includes a function called SetConsoleCurserPosition: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition.
I used this function a few years ago.